# How can I find what options an rpm was compiled with

Tags: rpm

I need to find the compile options for exim, as packaged by fedora 11. More generally, is there an easy way to find what options a particular rpm was compiled with?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the closest thing you can do (that I'm aware of) is to query the `OPTFLAGS` variable
of the exim package:

```
 [root@fedora11 ~]# rpm -q --queryformat="%{NAME}: %{OPTFLAGS}\n" exim
 exim: -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector
 --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic
 [root@fedora11 ~]#
```

You'll get better answer, however, if you download the source rpm of exim (`rpm -qivp exim*.rpm` shows the filename in the "`Source RPM`" tag) and install it with "`rpm -i exim-4.69-10.fc11.src.rpm`". Then look into the exim `.spec` file in the `/usr/src/redhat/SPECS/` directory (if you do this as root; this location can vary) and see how exactly it was configured and built. There you'll e.g. also find the `configure` options that were specified.

(You can also use `rpm2cpio exim-4.69-10.fc11.src.rpm | cpio -id` to extract the contents of the src rpm (including the `.spec` file) to the current directory instead of installing it.)